# node.js eventEmitter setImmediate vs. async

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, eventemitter

I was reading up on the [eventEmitter](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_asynchronous_vs_synchronous) documentation and came across the section where they discuss async vs synchronous code. They have this example that showcases how to process an event asynchronously:

```
const myEmitter = new MyEmitter();
myEmitter.on('event', (a, b) => {
  setImmediate(() => {
    console.log('this happens asynchronously');
  });
});
```

My question is: would using the `async` keyword not achieve the same thing?

Wouldn't the following implementation also run asynchronously?

```
const myEmitter = new MyEmitter();
myEmitter.on('event', async () => {
  console.log('does this happens asynchronously????');
});
```

Comment: setImmediate is not like `async`, quite the opposite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may help if you tell us why you think those would be the same.

The second function will execute on the event even though it is marked async (it will just return a promise that won't be used anywhere).

The first will also execute on the event but schedule its inner contents (the function that you pass to `setImmediate`) to be run when the event queue is empty.

`async` doesn't mean "do later" it just means "wrap my return in a promise automagically and allow me to use `await` in my function body".